# Can a function be used in $(( func arg ? str1 : str2 ))?

Tags: bash, function, arithmetic-expressions

I'd like to use a statement like this:

```
var=$(( func arg ? str1 : str2 ))
```

but bash gives this syntax error message:

```
syntax error in expression (error token is "arg")
```

I've played with various forms but I can't figure out how to make it accept a function with argument.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the correct answer is that there is no way to use the statement I asked about.  The problem is that this conditional operator can only evaluate to an integer and not a string as I wanted to do.

jm666 answered the question in a comment to Steve's answer so I gave him an up vote.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo $(( $(seq 1) + 1 ))
2
```

You need to use the same syntax as bash expects elsewhere. As far as the conditional ? iftrue : iffalse syntax, I don't think you can do that in bash. Instead, you can do something like:

```
echo $(( 1 + $(true && echo 1 || echo 0) ))
2
```

Comment: according to bash manual (section 6.5) the construction expr ? expr : expr is correct.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the correction. So it works within the arithmetic evaluation, e.g. $(( 0 ? 1 : 2 )) results in 2. However, based on the original question, a syntax like var=$(func $([[ arg -eq "something"]] && str1 || str2)) might be more appropriate.

Comment: yes, the conditional operator **works only with arithmetic evaluation**. (and only with integers)... :)